# JQuery even firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a text area that's meant to mimic the effects of a chat box I.E. when I press enter it makes an AJAX request. The problem is that the request is made twice:

```
$('html').on('keyup', '#message-text', function(e){
  if(e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({...},
      success: function(){
        console.log("*****POST****");
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log("failure");
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Whenever I press enter, the AJAX request is made successfully twice and in the console `****POST****` is logged twice when the button is pressed once. The source for one log is from `messages.js:43` (my file) and a file I'm not familiar with `VM3339:43`. What's the issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you've bound that event handler more than once?

Comment: Is there a chance that two elements with the ID `message-text` exist in the document?

Comment: show the code where this part is included, as Pointy says, it looks like its bound twice.

Comment: You can add a `console.log()` call with a prominent message right *before* the call to `.on()` to see if that's happening.

Comment: Here's my entire Javascript file: https://dpaste.de/9Bx7 - I've renamed the text area ID to avoid confusion. When I run `$('#message-input-text').count` I get 1

Comment: @Pointy you mean just before the line `$('html').on('keyup', '#message-input-text', function(e)`?

Comment: Chrome latest and Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Test it on e.g FF, same issue?

Comment: Still sends twice on FF.

Comment: So you surely binding event twice, including maybe script twice or... if you provide online link, this could be checked

Comment: @Nanor yes exactly, in order to see if somehow that code is running twice. Each call to `.on()` will add another handler, and all such handlers will be called when the event happens. Alternatively you could change `e.stopPropagation()` to `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: Heh, just discovered `stopImmediatePropagation()`. Would you post it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead of `.stopPropagation()`, you'll kill the event before any redundant handlers are invoked.

Now, of course, if that works, then it means that your setup code is running twice, perhaps because the script file is inadvertently imported in two  `<script>` tags. There's nothing bad about `.stopImmediatePropagation()`, but it'd probably be good to get rid of whatever's causing the code to run twice.